# Kentico use data in memory for Web Parts visibility

Tags: kentico

We are developing a site on which we want to authenticate the user by calling an external service. When the user is authenticated we are receiving the user profile and I want to use profile data for populating content elements, like static text web part, or use it for visibility conditions.
The problem is that I do not want to store the data in the `UserSettings` or custom tables, as the request is to keep the profile data in memory only.
As the calls are done through custom Web Parts, a solution would be to store the profile received from external service into Session and then use it in pages by calling `{% Session["Name"] %}` or by using `SessionHelper`.
It seems that the Session access is working from within Web Parts code only, but not from pages content.
I also tried using custom fields not stored in the database, but for some reason they are also not visible with `{% CurrentUser.UserSettings.ItemsAsFields.Name #%}`.
Is there a way to store and access data in memory without creating custom fields stored in database?
Also is there a way to authenticate a user in Kentico without having the actual user information in the database?

Comment: what do you mean by "pages content"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy solution is to still use the Session, and just create a custom Macro Method to get the Session value.

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Registering+custom+macro+methods

Just be careful, storing data per user in session can inflate the memory greatly if the Session is InProc, you may want to switch to SQL based session if your IIS server starts getting to high in memory.

Next question on authenticating a user without having user information, you need to at minimum have a basic User account created (with IsExternal set to true), you don't need to really go beyond that, but Kentico really needs a User in the CMS_User in order to do a lot of it's operations.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your environment you may need to [use SQL Server Session](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+web+farm+servers#Configuringwebfarmservers-Storingsessionstateonawebfarm) vs. InProc to work properly.  More specifically, if you're environment includes a web farm, session is recommended to persist in the database.  In previous implementations, I used Session without issue to do as you describe.

The major hurdle I came across was the massive amounts of memory this user data took up as traffic increased to the site.  What we ended up doing is storing the custom user info in a custom table as XML data and then accessed it as needed within the site.

One thing I did to ensure the sessions were cleaned up is to create a [custom scheduled task](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Scheduling+custom+tasks) to check the date the data was created and if it was older than XX hours or days, we removed it.  OR if a user clicked the log out button, the record was removed in a [custom global event](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Handling+global+events).

Comment: Shouldn't using [session timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx) be enough to clean up old sessions?

Comment: Should be although due to the amount of traffic and session data we were storing, we decided to move it out of session and store it in the database.  Which is why we needed to create the custom events.

Comment: IC. I thought you used `sessionState="SQLServer"`... then the session provider should do that OOTB.